# How does 'screen' impact environment variables?

Tags: gnu-screen, environment-variables

I noticed a difference in 'env' before and after a 'screen' call, is there any additional clarity on what gets called (for setting environment variables)?

I couldn't see any clear explanation from a quick search on 'man screen'

Some googled queries on the topic:

http://alan.lamielle.net/2009/03/09/environment-variables-and-gnu-screen

https://superuser.com/questions/105954/updating-screen-session-environment-variables-to-reflect-new-graphical-login

I guess a more specific sub-question would be, what is not instantiated in a screen session vs. that of a normal log-in?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A process inherits the environment variables from the parent, this means the first time you call `screen` (create a new one) it has a copy of all the environment variables of the parent process. Now `screen` adjusts/creates some variables like `COLUMNS`, `LINES`, `TERM`, `TERMCAP`, `WINDOW` and `STY`. You can also adjust or delete environment variables in your `screenrc` with `setenv`/`unsetenv`.

On some systems, `screen` is setuid or setgid in order to update [`utmp` and `wtmp`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utmp); then a few more variables are removed from the environment when `screen` starts, such as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

If you attach to an existing `screen` session your environment variables won't be copied as the `screen` process already exists and has it own environment variables (from the time when you started the process before). This means your changed environment variables won't be visible in the processes started by screen as they are copied from the parent process which has the old environment variables.